# Setting time format preference in unix (Mac-Terminal)

Tags: unix, terminal, snow-leopard

I'm learning to work in unix using Terminal on a Mac and I'd like to set the default listing for the timestamp to display in 12 hour time, using AM and PM, instead of 24 hour time (ie: 1:00 PM, not 13:00). I'm somewhat familiar with setting preferences, so to speak, using the `~/.bashrc` file, where I've set a couple of aliases, including one with the options for my preferred `ls` display. I've looked at the man pages and elsewhere online, but I haven't had any luck finding what I'm looking for time-wise though. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to set the time format on a UNIX global level so that all commands and output displays the time as per your format of choice?

Comment: Yes, that sums up what I'd like to do.

Comment: I wish I knew a way to format `ls` datetimes (I'd rather see ISO-8601). Apple's BSD manual for `ls` seems to offer nothing for formatting datetimes, other than changing timezone and sorting by datetime rather than alpha. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU ls, on Linux, there is a `--time-style` flag you can use to specify one of a few pre-defined time types, or specifying a completely custom `+FORMAT` style like the `date` command accepts. However, BSD ls, which Apple ships, does not support this flag.

I've seen similar discrepancies in commands like `date` and `tar` as well, all rooted in the differences between the GNU and BSD variants.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac OS terminal uses a bash shell. The prompt is controlled by the `PS1` environment variable described more [here](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html). Try this for example.

```
export PS1='\t$ '
```

It will give you a prompt looking something like this

```
19:40:14$
```

Comment: This didn't accomplish what I was trying to do, however it tipped me off to how I could customize the prompt (I'm not sure if that's what it's called) which is something I wanted to do, but wasn't going to hassle about. I came up with a partial answer by way of a video tutorial and through a concentrated look at the man pages for strftime. I'll start a new post to try to make my rephrasing of the question more useful to the community. Thanks~B

Comment: Actually, I changed my mind; this is probably the appropriate place to post, so I'll continue with a bit of extra space...<br/>  </br/> In the tutorial I mentioned above, there was information about configuring

Comment: Oi... this is getting to be a pain. I overshot my time for editing the last mistake (over 5 minutes). I'm not really getting the formatting on here and my patience for fussing with it at the moment has worn out. I'll give it a rest for now...

Answer (score 1):

`man date`

Check out the "+format" option.  You could create a shell alias to display the date using a custom format.

If you're referring to the time format used by 'ls', I don't believe there is any way to change that.

Comment: Thanks, you may be right about ls. I was able to customize the history format using the HISTTIMEFORMAT environment variable. HISTTIMEFORMAT='%b %d %I:%M:%S %p ' formats the date to show as: Jan 17 12:00:00 PM. I opted not to include the year for practical purposes, since it's just history, but I don't see any sort of straightforward way to format the string for time globally. Probably something with TZ, but that looks a bit more complicated than I can figure out at the moment. ~B

Answer (score 0):

to get 12:00 AM/PM use

```
  export PS='\@'
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. Welcome to S.O. Please remember to accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the checkmark sign, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoHL5.png. When you see good Q&A, vote them up by using the gray triangles,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNvfO.png.  Note that 'giving' reputation points to others does not mean a deduction to your reputation points.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything (at least not that I'm aware of) but thanks for the suggestion